# Нужно разделить строку на список в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня возникла проблема. У меня, например, есть строка
`1 1 4 5 7 5`. Как считать её из файла и сделать из неё список?

Comment: Проблема в чем, как прочитать строку или сделать список? Покажите ваш пример.

Comment: строку я прочитал, нужно сделать список(за это время я это уже сделал), я извиняюсь за изменение вопроса, теперь у меня есть список и переменная N которая например равна 4. Как сделать так чтобы из списка бралось значение индекс которого равен N. Типа x = z[N]

Comment: @redgartson чем не подходит функция split?

Comment: я так и не понял, вы разбили строку на элементы в список, и вам надо получить N -ый элемент, что мешает вам просто взять его из списка?

Answer (score 5):

```
a = "1 1 4 5 7 5"
a = a.split()
# результат ['1', '1', '4', '5', '7', '5']
```

Список проиндексирован от 0 до последнего номера списка (0 включён, последнее число, равное длине списка, не включено). Обращаться по индексу можно так:

```
 x = a[0] # Присвоить x первый элемент в списке.
```

Либо в цикле:

```
for i in range(len(a)): # Пробежаться по диапазону от 0 до длины списка с шагом 1. i - номер от 0 до len(a).
    print(a[i]) #Вывести элемент списка а, обратившись к нему по индексу.
```

Но на практике так делают редко. Обычно итерируют сам список для различных операций таким образом:

```
for i in a: # Пробежаться по всем элементам списка. i - элемент списка.
    print(i) # Вывести значение текущего в цикле элемента цикла.
```

Также можно использовать List comprehensions, но на первом этапе можете обойтись без них.

Comment: строку я прочитал, нужно сделать список(за это время я это уже сделал), я извиняюсь за изменение вопроса, теперь у меня есть список и переменная N которая например равна 4. Как сделать так чтобы из списка бралось значение индекс которого равен N. Типа x = z[N] – redgartson 1 час назад

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич  Сори, не посмотрел) Добавил.